# User that has < 100 reputation has posted a question with a Bounty of 100, how is that possible?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

I came across this featured question [How are unsaved/temporary edits stored during versioned editing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258566/how-are-unsaved-temporary-edits-stored-during-versioned-editing) I was curious as to how that was allowed to occur? I haven't seen that type of situation prior to this, nor found any answers to this.

More curious than anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bounty reputation is removed when the bounty is *offered*, not when it is awarded.  Basically the user has offered more than half of their reputation as bounty for that Q&A.

From my own reputation activity page when I've *offered* a bounty:

[image]

Yet the bounty wasn't awarded until a week later. This is the reputation activity from the user who earned the bounty.

[image]

So if the user had say 195 reputation, then offered a bounty of 100, they would then have 95 rep.

Bounties are non-refundable, whether the bounty is awarded or not.

---

Also, see [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for a more detailed description of how bounties work.